# Why can't I use the value of my selected option?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm building a form consisting in two selects: one for a list Gitlab projects and one for a list of Clockify projects. In each select, my options are an array of projects, with label being the projects name and the value being the project id.

```
class NewDashboard extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      gitlabId: '',
      clockifyId: ''
    }
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    change({ 'gitlabId': event.target.value, 'clockifyId': event.target.value })

  };

render() {

const { gitlabId, clockifyId } = this.props.form
const { projects, projTime } = this.props

if (projects) {
      gitlabProjs = projects.map(project => ({
        value: project.id,
        label: project.namespace.name + ": " + project.name,
      }));
      console.log(gitlabProjs)
    }

if (projTime) {
      clockifyProjs = projTime.timeEntries.map((timeEntry) => ({
        value: timeEntry.project.id,
        label: timeEntry.project.name,
      }));
      // console.log(clockifyProjs)
    }
...
```

The problem is: I can't seem to access my selected option value (project id), as it returns undefined.

```
<Select
      value={gitlabId.value}
      type="search"
      options={gitlabProjs}
      onChange={e => {
        change({ 'gitlabId': gitlabProjs.value })
                 console.log(gitlabProjs.value)
      }}
      placeholder="Projeto no Gitlab..."
></Select>
```

I'm probably doing this the wrong way. Does anyone know what the problem might be? (I'm a react beginner).

Comment: Which version of `react-select` are you using?

Comment: Hey - just to be clear, do you mean you can't access your selected value inside the callback function passed as onChange to Select?

Comment: @Rallen I'm currently using ```react-select@2.4.2```

Comment: @SrikkantSrinivasan yes. I want to set ```gitlabId``` value to the value of my selected option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onChange` prop expects a function which accepts the selected value as the first argument (typings: `One of <Object, Array<Object>, null, undefined>`). So using `event.target.value` has no effect.

Also the `value` prop itself accepts an object that it will display as selected value. So you can either save the whole option object and give that to the `value` prop:

```
handleChange = (option) => {
    change({'gitlabId': option, 'clockifyId': option});
}

<Select
    { ... }
    value={gitlabId}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

or you can save the value of the option and then filter through your options array to find the selected value:

```
handleChange = (option) => {
    change({'gitlabId': option.value, 'clockifyId': option.value});
}

<Select
    { ... }
    value={gitlabProjs.find((val) => val.value === gitlabId)}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Also on a sidenote: The prop `type` has no effect as it is not required by the `Select` component.

Edit: Reference: [`react-select` prop documentation](https://react-select.com/props)

Comment: It makes sense that I need to filter the options to find my selected value. However, it still isn't working because of my ```change()``` form action: 

```change: (field) => ({ field })```  that I have in my logic file. 

I still have to have something like 
```onChange={e => {
              change({ 'gitlabId': something })
            }}``` 

in my ```onChange``` prop.

Comment: And that `something` is `e`, because `e` is no Event object but an object representing the selected option instead.

Answer (score 0):

can you change the current onChange function in the Select to:

```
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

and add a console.log(event) to your handleChange function

Comment: I get an ```Uncaught ReferenceError: change is not defined``` error

Comment: podes mostrar um bocado mais do teu render onde o Select monta?